# Python Weirdness on Terminal Open

Tags: python

When I open Terminal I see the following:

```
Last login: Wed Feb  8 18:30:05 on ttys029
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.py", line 75, in emit
    self.doRollover()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.py", line 132, in doRollover
    os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1472, in shutdown
    h.flush()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 740, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1472, in shutdown
    h.flush()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 740, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Everything seems to work but this is ugly and maybe warns of future trouble.  I've installed Python 2.7 on this machine, then removed it to a virtualenv to restore 2.6 as the system default.

Any thoughts on how I can debug this?

**EDIT:**

My `.profile` has a call to `virtualenvwrapper.sh` -- which, as I look it, is located under `.../Versions/2.7` of Python.  So maybe I should look for the problem there?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but why is python loading anything when you start Terminal.app?  Do you have something specific in your .bashrc or .profile that executes some python code?

Comment: Yeah, virtualenvwrapper.sh, see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, that's it -- pointing .profile to /Versions/Current/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh makes the cruft go away.  Phrase as an answer and I'll choose it.

Comment: Looks like you answered it yourself.  Its ok to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

From comment:

Check your `.bashrc` or `.profile` for Python specific code -- if you find something there make sure it is pointing to the correct version, be it `.../Versions/Current/...`, `.../Versions/2.7/...`, or whatever.

Comment: The issue is correct but the solution is not necessarily - your current python might not be the one you want if you have multiple pythons

Comment: @Mark:  How's this?